# Due to engine myisam ,failed to created table mysql Db by Spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am getting exception "org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException" for follwing query in intellij tool.

Error executing DDL "create table employee_information (pk varchar(255) not null, _name varchar(255), age integer not null, office_location varchar(255), position varchar(255), salary double precision not null, start_date date, primary key (pk)) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement

Comment: I've seen that error before... someone really needs to make InnoDB the default MySQL engine in Hibernate. In my opinion, [no one should be using MyISAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb/17706717#17706717).

Comment: Weird, I get this error using both default settings in Google SQL Cloud and Spring Boot. One would think that these kind of issues would work by default

Answer (score 4):

Just add spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect in application.properties file to solve java.sql.SQLException: Storage engine MyISAM is disabled (Table creation is disallowed